# Repeated animation

Tags: animation, keyframes

I am trying to animate the action of a clock escapement. The wheel is biased to anticlockwise rotation but restrained by the fork which reciprocates about its pivot. The first bunch of key frames are the wheel snapping round one notch before it is caught by the upper fork. The second bunch of key frames are the wheel being let go by the top of the fork and caught by the lower fork. There is a dwell between. (The animation covers 2PI/15 rotation of the wheel.)

I want to repeat this cycle but not return the wheel to zero each time. I have tried umpteen experiments with cycles, delta transforms and delta keyframes without success. Can someone kindly point me in the right direction please?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

<sub>OP: Skip to step 5.</sub>
You can use a [cyclic modifier with an offset](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/modifiers.html#cycles).

1. Select the wheel (or whatever objects animation should be extrapolated).
2. Go to the graph editor.
3. RMB select the curve(s) in question. In this case it will probably be the Z rotation curve.
4. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and choose *Make Cyclic*. In the <kbd>N</kbd> Panel of the graph editor you can see the **cyclic modifier** which was added. You could also add the modifier with the dropdown menu. As you noted, right now the modifier will by truly cyclic and snap back to the first key after the last key.
5. Make the modifier [cyclic with an **offset**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/modifiers.html#cycles), by choosing **Repeat with Offset** from the dropdown menu in the f-curve modifier.

[image: cyclic modifier settings]

Comment: Thanks. I went back to trying Cycles and found my problem. When you repeat a cycle of 48 frames in my case (1 to 48), Blender starts cycle No2 on frame 48 not on 49 thus losing one frame every cycle. If you give it 49 frames to repeat (0 to 48) then it accumulates frames at 48 per cycle and the animation works.